# Why Xdb.Collection.Shard0, Xdb.Collection.Shard1 and Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager databases in Sitecore 9 are not Partially Contained?

Tags: xdb, sitecore-install-framework, sql-database

I am wondering what are the reasons or maybe technical limitations all of Sitecore 9 databases to be Partially Contained except Xdb.Collection.Shard0, Xdb.Collection.Shard1 and Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager.

Comment: Thank you Rosen for sharing this link about Contained Databases https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2014-contained-databases/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

xConnect uses a change tracking functionality which requires a SQL User so it can access multiple databases. For this reason, contained database authentication cannot be used on the xDB Collection databases (shards and shard manager).

Source info (from @Rosen Petrov): https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/18/video-introduction-to-sql-server-change-tracking/

Comment: Some source of info for those who are not familiar: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/18/video-introduction-to-sql-server-change-tracking/

Comment: Thank you Rosen, I added that into the answer for any who need it!